# When using Bootstrap "row" and "col-lg-3" classes, all the columns get height of longest column. How to fix this?

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm developing a simple layout using Bootstrap. It loads some data to columns using "row" and "col-lg-3" class. There are 4 columns in the view under "row" class. In the "col-lg-3" class, i added another "row" class and divided it into 2 columns of "col-lg-6". Please check the code here. Then it is easy to understand.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-3"
         style="background-color: #cecece;border-right: 5px solid #cecece;border-left: 5px solid #cecece; border-radius: 10px;margin-right: 5px;">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-6">
                <img style="max-width: 80%;max-height: 100px;margin-top:10px;" src="../static/images/gohugo-default-sample-hero-image.jpg"
                     class="img"
                     alt="image">
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-6">
                <img style="max-width: 80%;max-height: 100px;margin-top:10px;" src="static/images/coding/netifly.png"
                     class="img"
                     alt="image">
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-6">
                <img style="max-width: 80%;max-height: 100px;margin-top:10px;" src="static/images/coding/netifly.png"
                     class="img"
                     alt="image">
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-6">
                <img style="max-width: 80%;max-height: 100px;margin-top:10px;" src="static/images/coding/netifly.png"
                     class="img"
                     alt="image">
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-6">
                <img style="max-width: 80%;max-height: 100px;margin-top:10px;" src="static/images/coding/netifly.png"
                     class="img"
                     alt="image">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3"
         style="background-color: #cecece;border-right: 5px solid #cecece;border-left: 5px solid #cecece; border-radius: 10px;margin-right: 5px;">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-6">
                <img style="max-width: 80%;max-height: 100px;margin-top:10px;" src="../static/images/gohugo-default-sample-hero-image.jpg"
                     class="img"
                     alt="image">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is a sample snippet from my original code. I only added 2 columns to show you. And please check the output here.

[image]

You can see the output. First column has 5 items and it's loaded in 3 rows. Second column has one item. But the issue is the background color. 
In second column, I only need "gray" color to the item row. Not to other 2 rows there. It has bottom empty space. How to reduce that ? 
Every time all the columns take the height of the longest column. I need to make these columns independent. Please help me on this. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are close. You can solve this by putting each of the left and right columns within another div, this time the full width of the Bootstrap grid space (12 columns). Set this new div with your background styling and leave the first column unstyled.

Something like this:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-3">
            <div class="col-lg-12" style="background-color: #cecece;border-right: 5px solid #cecece;border-left: 5px solid #cecece; border-radius: 10px;margin-right: 5px;">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-6">
                        <img style="max-width: 80%;max-height: 100px;margin-top:10px;" src="../static/images/gohugo-default-sample-hero-image.jpg"
                             class="img"
                             alt="image">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-6">
                        <img style="max-width: 80%;max-height: 100px;margin-top:10px;" src="static/images/coding/netifly.png"
                             class="img"
                             alt="image">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-6">
                        <img style="max-width: 80%;max-height: 100px;margin-top:10px;" src="static/images/coding/netifly.png"
                             class="img"
                             alt="image">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-6">
                        <img style="max-width: 80%;max-height: 100px;margin-top:10px;" src="static/images/coding/netifly.png"
                             class="img"
                             alt="image">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-6">
                        <img style="max-width: 80%;max-height: 100px;margin-top:10px;" src="static/images/coding/netifly.png"
                             class="img"
                             alt="image">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-3">
            <div class="col-lg-12" style="background-color: #cecece;border-right: 5px solid #cecece;border-left: 5px solid #cecece; border-radius: 10px;margin-right: 5px;">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-6">
                        <img style="max-width: 80%;max-height: 100px;margin-top:10px;" src="../static/images/gohugo-default-sample-hero-image.jpg"
                             class="img"
                             alt="image">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

try add `background-color: #cecece` to `.col-lg-6`

```css
.col-lg-6 {
  background-color: #cecece;
}
```

```html
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-3">
                <div class="col-lg-12" style="border-radius: 10px;overflow: hidden;margin-right: 5px;">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-lg-6">
                            <img style="max-width: 80%;max-height: 100px;margin-top:10px;" src="../static/images/gohugo-default-sample-hero-image.jpg"
                                 class="img"
                                 alt="image">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-6">
                            <img style="max-width: 80%;max-height: 100px;margin-top:10px;" src="static/images/coding/netifly.png"
                                 class="img"
                                 alt="image">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-6">
                            <img style="max-width: 80%;max-height: 100px;margin-top:10px;" src="static/images/coding/netifly.png"
                                 class="img"
                                 alt="image">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-6">
                            <img style="max-width: 80%;max-height: 100px;margin-top:10px;" src="static/images/coding/netifly.png"
                                 class="img"
                                 alt="image">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-6">
                            <img style="max-width: 80%;max-height: 100px;margin-top:10px;" src="static/images/coding/netifly.png"
                                 class="img"
                                 alt="image">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-3">
                <div class="col-lg-12" style="background-color: #cecece;border-right: 5px solid #cecece;border-left: 5px solid #cecece; border-radius: 10px;margin-right: 5px;">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-lg-6">
                            <img style="max-width: 80%;max-height: 100px;margin-top:10px;" src="../static/images/gohugo-default-sample-hero-image.jpg"
                                 class="img"
                                 alt="image">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put another div for each two columns with 12 grid system.

Comment: This is the same answer that I gave.